# Parsing Json data from a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am building a Node JS application that reads file that contains array of Json objects, and displays it on a table. I need to parse the JSON data array.
sample json data:

```
[{"name":"Ken", "Age":"25"},{"name":"Pulsar", "Age":30}]
```

I have used the following to read from file and pass it into another json object:

```
const fileRead = fs.readFileSync("/Users/mken/Desktop/Node JS/DATA-TABLE/public/files/data.json", (err, data)=>{
console.log(JSON.parse(data))
return JSON.parse(data);
```

});

```
console.log(fileRead)
```

The expected output is array of JSON objects. However, when I console.log the fileRead, I do not get intended output:[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSzlh.png)

I further intend to iterate through the data read above and pass it to a JSON object:

```
const data = {headers:["Name", "Age"], rows: fileRead.foreach((row)=>{return row.name, row.age];})}
```

Please check and advise.

Comment: Try using the encoding option in [fs.readFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options)

Comment: fs.readFileSync is synchronous and doesn't require callback function. Your data is returned and stored into fileRead constant. Just log fileRead and you'll see your data. fs.readFile in another hand is asynchronous, thats when you want to use callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Thanks to: https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs
try {
  const data = fs.readFileSync('test.txt', 'utf8');
  console.log(data);
  const json = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(json);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with encoding. I passed utf-8 to filereadsync as second parameter, and it worked.
Thank you

Answer (score -2):

If I do your task, I'll save data on a table, then I'll paste data to a json file and I'll read the file like your code.

I do that because I want to control the format of the JSON file. If you save a manual file in JSON, there are many ways you have problems with formatting JSON.

I hope my answer is helpful. Good luck!